# Show Event Custom Fields in Reports

Tags: civievent, civireport

I have an event with custom fields that I use to collect information relevant to each participant's registration (for example, number of guests accompanying, seat preference, etc.). When I view the participants under the "Manage Events" view, it will show me the fee levels and quantities they selected, but not the custom fields. I have to click on each participant to view the content of the custom fields.

How can I generate a report that will show the custom fields? When I try to generate a custom report, the custom fields don't appear as columns I can select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thought: go into the config for your custom fields and check the box that says 'Searchable'!

That will then make that field available in all reports that pull in custom fields on specific entities.

If you still don't see it in the report you want to see it in - then installl Fuzion's Extended Reports extension!

Comment: Making the fields searchable was the key. That's three hours of futility gone!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Thanks for comfirming - this is sure to help someone else save some time!

Comment: i find it a shame (that i admit i have not chosen to provide a PR for) that 'required' is a default 'yes' field on fields, but searchable is default 'no' - to me the opposite is the case for >90% of fields we create

Comment: I agree! Most people will want to report on their own generated fields 